# Queue put and get out of order in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a question regarding the multiprocessing module in python.
I am reading from a folder of jsons, these jsons are named in ascending order. 
Each of these jsons contain data for four different csv’s I need to write the parsed json data to. To two of the csv’s I need to write one row, to the other two I need to write multiple rows per json-file.

It is crucial that the order of writing to the csv is preserved from the ascending order of the json-naming. Since these jsons are really big I do not want to keep all of the read jsons in memory, but would prefer to use some sort of buffered-queue where a certain amount of elements are enqueued, and then asynchronously are dequeued. 
Now I have been trying to implement this using `multiprocessing.Pool` and `starmap` to enqueue, but the order seems to be in disarray. Does anyone have a suggestion how to approach this problem, is a queue even the right approach? I would like to optimize using all resources on my machine. Thanks

```py
def read_from_queue(queue, max_items):
    """ read from queue until max_items has been reached"""
    items_read = 0
    while items_read < max_items:
        try:
            item = queue.get()
            items_read += 1
            print(item)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass


def enqueue_item(queue, item):
    """ enqueuing an item """
    print(item)
    queue.put(item)


def process_csv(input_folder, output_folder, workers):
    # creating the abspath for each element in folder
    input_filepaths = [f"{input_folder}/{elem}" for elem in os.listdir(input_folder)]
    # sort the jsons by prefix 00001_...99999_
    input_filepaths = sorted(input_filepaths, key=lambda x: int(os.path.basename(x).split("_")[0]))

    # context manager for multiprocessing
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        # shared queue instance
        queue = manager.Queue()
       
        # pool instance using n workers
        with multiprocessing.Pool(workers) as pool:
            # assembling ars to be called on
            items_to_enqueue = [(queue, input_filepath)
                                    for input_filepath in input_filepaths]

            # enqueuing the items
            pool.starmap(enqueue_item, items_to_enqueue, 1)

            # dequeue the items
            deuqued_tasks = [pool.apply_async(read_from_queue, (queue, workers))]

            # the items are in disarray
            print(deuqued_tasks[0].get())

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   process_csv(input_folder, output_folder, workers=num_workers)
```

Comment: what exactly are you doing with the `json` files ? and what are you doing to the csv files ? the code in the question doesn't seem related to your actual use case, also introducing multiprocessing here is not simple, as you may have noticed.